# Running Primefaces Cookbook showcase on TomEE

Tags: primefaces, apache-tomee

I'm having trouble to run the new Primefaces Cookbook showcase https://github.com/ova2/primefaces-cookbook in Eclipse Luna using TomEE 1.71 webprofile using JDK 1.7_51

I imported the project as "existing maven project" and the projects builds fine, but if I run it on TomEE I just get an empty page popping up (http://localhost:8080/showcase/views/home.jsf). There are now errors in the server log.

PS: I also tried to deploy their compiled WARs on a standalone TomEE (outside of Eclipse), same issue.

Comment: Tried to use 'view-source' in the browser? What did you see?

Comment: it's empty (it just defines a ui:composition 8with template location etc, but no body). I tried WildFly8, there it opens http://localhost:8080/pf-cookbook/views/home.jsf, but i just get some menu items (and a broken image) without functionality...